# JavaFX. Text + Hyperlink

Tags: javafx

Как сделать: "Простой текст - [Ссылка](http://google.com)"

Я делаю:

```
Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink("Ссылка");    
Label label = new Label("Простой текст - ");
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.getChildren().addAll(label,hyperlink);
bottomBorderPane.setCenter(pane);
```

Но в итоге hyperlink и label отображаются поверх друг друга, да и еще не в центре bottomBorderPane, а слева ...

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться контейнером TextFlow.

Comment: bottomTextFlow.getChildren().addAll(label,hyperlink); Вывел нормально, только как его заставить отображать содержимое по центру? а не слева...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink( "Ссылка" );    
Label label = new Label( "Простой текст - " );
HBox hBox = new HBox();
hBox.setAlignment( Pos.CENTER );
hBox.getChildren().addAll( label, hyperlink );
//далее вставляем куда угодно
bottomBorderPane.setCenter( pane );
```

Comment: Спасибо - то, что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Pane - общий класс с базовыми возможностями компоновки. Используйте StackPane.

Comment: bottomStackPane.getChildren().addAll(label,hyperlink);  то же выводит одно поверх другого...

Comment: label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);  hyperlink.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

Comment: Все равно накладывались друг на друга.